# List of File to array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm wondering, why is there a problem to change `Arraylist` of `File` to an array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> pl = new ArrayList<File>();
    pl.add(new File ("C:\\folder"));
    String[] k;
    k = pl.toArray(new String[pl.size()]);
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

In a simple example above I will get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

and second question: Do I have to pass size of Arraylist? Because both version works fine with arraylist of strings:

```
k = pl.toArray(new String[pl.size()]);
k = pl.toArray(new String[] {});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to convert a list of files into a list of string contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of `File` objects, you can't just put them in an array of `String`, you'll need to explicitly convert them somehow (e.g. by calling `File#getName()`). The most convenient way of doing this is probably with a `Stream`:

```
k = p1.stream().map(File::getName).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert Path to String when you want to map a `List<Path>` into an array.

Here what you could write (I add some comment about changes) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> pl = new ArrayList<>(); // Diamond operator
    pl.add(new File ("C:\\folder"));
    File[] k = pl.toArray(new File[pl.size()]);
    k = pl.stream().toArray(File[]::new);  // equivalent to the previous line
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(k)); // Array.toString is not overriden. So this is needed
}
```